# Guardar Datos de Inputs Dinámicos en la Base de Datos

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

Tengo que guardar información en la base de datos de dos campos. Los inputs son dinámicos se crean los que el usuario elija el problemas es que no me los inserta como debe de ser me inserta de la siguiente manera:

si inserto campo1="Juan" campo2="24";
en la base de datos se guardan asi

```
id     nombre    edad 
1      juan       juan
2       24        24
```

cuando se tienen que insertar así

```
id     nombre    edad 
1      juan        24
```

**Código HTML:**

```
<div id="elementos">
    <form id="datos" action="inserta.php" method="post">
        <div id="inputs">
            Nombre:<input id="dato1" type="text" name="dato1" />
            Edad:<input id="edad1" type="text" name="edad1" />

        </div>
        <input id="agrega" type="button" value="+" />
        <input id="enviar" type="button" value="Enviar" />
    </form>
</div>
```

**Código JQuery:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var cuentaInputs = $('#elementos').children().length;
    $('#agrega').click(function(){
        cuentaInputs++;
        $('<br class="fila'+cuentaInputs+'"/><label class="fila'+cuentaInputs+'" for="dato'+cuentaInputs+'">Nombre.'+cuentaInputs+':</label><input type="text" name="dato'+cuentaInputs+'" class="fila'+cuentaInputs+'" id="dato'+cuentaInputs+'"/><label class="fila'+cuentaInputs+'" for="edad'+cuentaInputs+'">Edad.'+cuentaInputs+':</label><input type="text" name="edad'+cuentaInputs+'" class="fila'+cuentaInputs+'" id="edad'+cuentaInputs+'"/>').appendTo('#inputs');

     });
    $('#enviar').click(function(){
        $('#datos').submit();
    });
});
</script>
```

**Código PHP:**

```
<?php 

$conexion = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

mysql_select_db("ejemplo",$conexion) or die ("Error");

foreach ($_POST as $key => $values) {

    $query="INSERT INTO prueba(nombre, edad) VALUES ('{$values}','{$values}')";
    $res=mysql_query($query, $conexion);
}


if ($res) {
    header("Location: ejemplo.php");

}else{
    echo  "Error";
}
```

Comment: ya lo había probado así y dio el mismo resultado :/

Comment: ¿Cuál es el resultado de `print_r($_POST);`?

Comment: Array ( [dato1] => antonio [edad1] => 12 [dato2] => juan [edad2] => 15 [dato3] => pedro [edad3] => 18 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basándome en el `print_r($_POST)` que nos copiaste, propongo esta solución utilizando los índices del array y modificando la estructura de generación de tu formulario html, para generar arrays multidimensionales:

jQuery:

```
$('#agrega').click(function(){
    cuentaInputs++;
    $('<br class="fila'+cuentaInputs+'"/><label class="fila'+cuentaInputs+'" for="usuario['+cuentaInputs+'][dato]">Nombre.'+cuentaInputs+':</label><input type="text" name="usuario['+cuentaInputs+'][dato]" class="fila'+cuentaInputs+'" id="dato'+cuentaInputs+'"/><label class="fila'+cuentaInputs+'" for="usuario['+cuentaInputs+'][edad]">Edad.'+cuentaInputs+':</label><input type="text" name="usuario['+cuentaInputs+'][edad]" class="fila'+cuentaInputs+'" id="edad'+cuentaInputs+'"/>').appendTo('#inputs');
 });
```

HTML:

```
Nombre:<input id="dato1" type="text" name="usuario[1][dato]" />
        Edad:<input id="edad1" type="text" name="usuario[1][edad]" />
```

PHP:

```
foreach ($_POST['usuario'] as $key => $values) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO prueba(nombre, edad) VALUES ('" .  $values['dato'] . "','" $values['edad'] . "')";
    $res=mysql_query($query, $conexion);
}
```

He cambiado un poco el uso de comillas, solo para hacer más legible el código, pero puedes mantener el estilo que usas actualmente.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda probe el codigo y me arrojo este error 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$value' (T_VARIABLE)

Comment: Puedes hacer un echo de una de las líneas de $query?

Comment: Solo Esta Tomando un valor INSERT INTO prueba(nombre, edad)VALUES('12','12')

Comment: Perdón, me confundí, ya lo corrijo.

Comment: Listo, he modificado toda la respuesta.

Comment: Lo estoy probando y arrojo este error:

Notice: Undefined index: usuario in C:\xampp\htdocs\ejemplo\inserta.php on line 8

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\ejemplo\inserta.php on line 8

Comment: y coloque el values de la siguiente manera para que no marcara error en el "value"

('".$value['dato']."','".$value['edad']."')

Comment: Ten en cuenta que en la solución propuesta estoy utilizando `$values` en plural, pero es irrelevante que sea en plural o singular, lo que importa es que coincida.

Puedes copiar de nuevo el resultado de `print_r($_POST)` con el nuevo html y jquery?

Comment: Array ( [dato1] => juan [edad1] => 16 [usuario] => Array ( [2] => Array ( [dato] => pedro [edad] => 20 ) ) )

Comment: Algo estás haciendo mal en la generación del HTML, pues deberías tener un solo array multidimensional, algo como `[usuario] => Array( [1] => Array (....) 2 => Array (....) )`

Comment: checando el query que tenia con el codigo desde el principio me di cuenta que inserta dos veces en ves de insertar solo una vez 
INSERT INTO prueba(nombre, edad)VALUES('juan','juan')INSERT INTO prueba(nombre, edad)VALUES('12','12')

Comment: Creo que no estoy siendo claro, yo hice modificaciones a tu código jQuery, de forma que los input de html se generen, si implementas esa parte correctamente, te va a funcionar el php propuesto en mi solución también. Lo que estás mostrando es simplemente el código SQL, pero eso es otra historia, y se puede optimizar fácilmente.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando vi este ejemplo estaba echo solo para un campo (un solo input) pero yo lo necesito para insertar mas de un input 
Con este codigo funciona para un campo 
HTML:

```
<div id="elementos">
    <form id="datos" action="inserta.php" method="post">
        <div id="inputs">
            Nombre:<input id="dato1" type="text" name="dato1" />


        </div>
        <input id="agrega" type="button" value="+" />
        <input id="enviar" type="button" value="Enviar" />
    </form>
</div>
```

JQUERY:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var cuentaInputs = $('#elementos').children().length;
    $('#agrega').click(function(){
        cuentaInputs++;
        $('<br class="fila'+cuentaInputs+'"/><label class="fila'+cuentaInputs+'" for="dato'+cuentaInputs+'">Nombre.'+cuentaInputs+':</label><input type="text" name="dato'+cuentaInputs+'" class="fila'+cuentaInputs+'" id="dato'+cuentaInputs+'"/>').appendTo('#inputs');

     });
 $('#enviar').click(function(){
            $('#datos').submit();
        });
    });

</script>
```

PHP:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $query="INSERT INTO prueba(nombre)VALUES('{$value}')";
    $res=mysql_query($query, $conexion);
}
```